# Insert statement with multiple Select statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query to insert some records using multiple Select statements
My query is as follows

```
    INSERT INTO tbl_StreetMaster
    (
    StreetName,
    CityID,
    StartPoint,
    EndPoint, 
    StoreID,
    IsActive,
    CreationDate,
    CreatedBy
    )

    SELECT

    (SELECT a.StreetName,CAST(a.CityName AS INT),a.EndPointFrom,a.EndPointTo
     FROM #TempRecords a 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT b.StreetID,b.StreetName FROM tbl_StreetMaster b 
   WHERE a.StreetName=b.StreetName and a.EndPointFrom=b.StartPoint and
   a.EndPointTo=b.EndPoint and CAST(a.CityName AS INT)=b.CityID and b.IsActive=1
     ))
     ,
     (SELECT  a.StoreID   FROM tbl_StoreGridMapping a
     inner join tbl_GridMaster b on a.GridID=b.GridID
      inner join #TempRecords c on b.GridCode=c.GridCode1
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT b.StreetID,b.StreetName FROM tbl_StreetMaster b
     WHERE c.StreetName=b.StreetName and c.EndPointFrom=b.StartPoint and
     c.EndPointTo=b.EndPoint and CAST(c.CityName AS INT)=b.CityID and b.IsActive=1))

     , 
     1,GETDATE(),100
```

Even though I have right number of columns in my Select it gives me error all the time

```
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items
than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT 
columns.
```

Can any one help out with this.

Comment: You can't have the same number in each otherwise you wouldn't be getting the error. I count `8` in the `insert` and `5` in the `select`

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I think you missed  `1,GETDATE(),100` from the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return multiple columns from a subselect (so the system is probably assuming one column from each subselect and counting five columns total, and not getting far enough to tell you that the subselects can only return 1 value.

I'm not clear why you haven't written it as a single query anyway:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_StreetMaster
(
StreetName,
CityID,
StartPoint,
EndPoint, 
StoreID,
IsActive,
CreationDate,
CreatedBy
)
SELECT
    c.StreetName,CAST(c.CityName AS INT),c.EndPointFrom,c.EndPointTo,
    a.StoreID, 1,GETDATE(),100
FROM tbl_StoreGridMapping a
 inner join tbl_GridMaster b on a.GridID=b.GridID
  inner join #TempRecords c on b.GridCode=c.GridCode1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT b.StreetID,b.StreetName FROM tbl_StreetMaster b
 WHERE c.StreetName=b.StreetName and c.EndPointFrom=b.StartPoint and
 c.EndPointTo=b.EndPoint and CAST(c.CityName AS INT)=b.CityID and b.IsActive=1)
```

Unless the mapping through `tbl_GridMaster` and `tbl_StoreGridMapping` may not exist (and you want a `null` for `StoreID`, in which case you might want to replace the `inner join`s with `right join`s.

I'd also query the wisdom (somewhere along the line) of casting a column called `CityName` to an `INT`. Something's broken there (in naming, if nothing else).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you put a union bewteen selects

like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(elem1,elem2,elem3) SELECT elem1,elem2,elem3 from table1 union select elem1,elem2,elem3 from table2 union select elem1,elem2,elem3 from table3
```